# jQuery UI how: Click a button and send the whole sortable list to another tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, list, tabs, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using the jquery sortable lists with tabs shown here
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists-through-tabs

What i need it to do is press a button, say "SEND ALL TO TAB 2", and all items of tab 1 are sent to tab 2.
Please, i really need this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to find all list items at tab 1, and append them to tab 2 list.

The following code is triggered when a button with id 'send_all' (consider placing it at the first tab) is pushed. It finds and moves all li items from 'sortable1' to 'sortable2', and then switches to the second tab.

```
$('#send_all').bind({
    'click': function(){ 
        $('#sortable1 li').each(function(){
            $(this).appendTo('#sortable2');
        });
        $tabs.tabs('select', 1 );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the button is a link with class transfer-items whose href points to the items container of the tab the items will be transfer to (in the ui example #tabs-1 #tabs-2):

```
$('a.transfer-items').click(function() {
  var itemsContainer = $('#tabs .ui-state-selected a').attr('href');
  var newList = $($(this).attr.href() + '.connectedSortable');
  $(itemsContainer + ' .connectedSortable li').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).appendTo(newList);
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you for the response but i think the guy above has a much cleaner answer. i appreciate it.